# Raspberry Pi Ultrasonic Range Finder with WebIOPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, webiopi

I am working on a project, to control a RC car with Raspberry Pi and have done it with he help of WeiOPi.

Now I wanted to add a Ultrasonic Range Finder on it (I have HC-SR04).
I googled in internet about it and didn't find much information, I have a question.
How I can combine the python code with java-script and html to print the Distance on the web page.

Thanks in advance,
Any Help will be appreciated.

Regards,
H.M

P.S, I am only 13 and new to Programming.

**EDIT:**

### **Unfinished Code:**

**The python code is:**

```
import webiopi
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG = 23
ECHO = 24

print "Distance Measurement In Progress"

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)

GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
print "Waiting For Sensor To Settle"
time.sleep(2)

GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
  pulse_start = time.time()

while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
  pulse_end = time.time()

pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

distance = pulse_duration * 17150
# _____________________________________________________________________
# I want to print the following string (distance) to print on html page
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
@webiopi.macro
def getSensor(channel):
    percent = round(distance, 2)
    return "%.2f%%" % percent

#Instantiate the server on the port 8000, it starts immediately in its own thread
server = webiopi.Server(port=8000)

# Run our loop until CTRL-C is pressed or SIGTERM received
webiopi.runLoop()

# -------------------------------------------------- #
# Termination part                                   #
# -------------------------------------------------- #

# Stop the server
server.stop()
```

**The html code:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        webiopi().ready(init);

        // defines function passed previously to webiopi().ready()
        function init() {
                // automatically refresh UI each seconds
                setInterval(updateUI, 1000);
        }

        // function called through setInterval
        function updateUI() {
                webiopi().callMacro("getSensor", 0, sensorCallback);
                webiopi().callMacro("getSensor", 1, sensorCallback);
                webiopi().callMacro("getSensor", 2, sensorCallback);
                webiopi().callMacro("getSensor", 3, sensorCallback);
        }       

        // callback function used to display sensor data
        function sensorCallback(macroName, channel, data) {
                // use jQuery to change spans content
                $("#sensor"+channel).text(data);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <div>Sensor 0: <span id="sensor0"></span></div>
        <div>Sensor 1: <span id="sensor1"></span></div>
        <div>Sensor 2: <span id="sensor2"></span></div>
        <div>Sensor 3: <span id="sensor3"></span></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming!  While this sounds like an interesting project, your question is really to broad for us to answer effectively.  You are basically asking, "how can I write a web application?", which is a large topic.  There are already a number of places to start, including I am sure a number of articles specifically about doing this sort of thing with a raspberry pi.  You will get better answers here if you can present us with actual code and specific error messages ("I wrote this, and expected it to do this, but instead it did this...").  Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I will provide the "unfinished" code. Thanks